# VBA to assign copied macro to target workbook instead of source workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm not a programmer and this is my first post, so any help or references would be appreciated.
From a source workbook (sourcebk), I'm trying to programmatically open a target workbook (targetbk), copy/import a module from the sourcebk to the targetbk, create a button on the targetbk then assign the imported macro to a targetbk. The code below works great with both sourcebk and targetbk open, but when I close sourcebk (which is my intention) the code keeps looking for sourcebk because apparently this code assigns the sourcebk macro (instead of the targetbk macro of the same name) to the button on targetbk. How do I assign the imported macro to the button on targetbk? I've seen and tried various code samples, but with no success so far.

Here are the relevant parts of the code:

```
‘Open target workbook
Dim TargetBk As Workbook, SourceBk As Workbook
Set TargetrBk = ActiveWorkbook
Dim fileNameAndPath As Variant
fileNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.XLS*), *.XLS*", Title:="Select File To Be Opened")

‘Transfer module
Dim filePath As String
filePath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
ThisWorkbook.Activate
ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Module1").Export (filePath + "\Anyname.bas")
TargetBk.Activate
ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Import (filePath + "\Anyname.bas")
Kill filePath + "\Anyname.bas"

‘Create button and assign Module
Dim btn As Object
Set w = Worksheets(1).Cells(4, 5)
Set btn = Worksheets(1).Buttons.Add(w.Left, w.Top, w.Width, w.Height)
With btn
  .OnAction = "[Module1_Name]"
  .Caption = "Do Something"
End With
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear from the code you've posted that it "assigns the sourcebk macro (instead of the targetbk macro of the same name) to the button on targetbk". Rather, it exports the code to a file (`Anyname.bas`), imports it into the Target Workbook, and then instructs the button to call `[Module1_Name]`:

```
.OnAction = "[Module1_Name]"
```

I gather that you've rewritten the module name in quotation marks, but the reference to the Source Workbook will be in that `OnAction` part or in the `Anyname.bas` code. If you can post the additional code, then I expect that we might be able to help you.